# Whatever happened to the Lurker Files?

Tags: scott-ciencin

[The Lurker Files](https://web.archive.org/web/19980121070621/http://www.randomhouse.com/lurkerfiles/) was a web-serial running between 1996 and 1997. In Wintervale University, the mysterious "Lurker"'s power is the anonymity and malleability of online activity - he assumes others' identities in chat rooms; entraps and blackmails students to do his bidding; and in general, brings to life a variety of dangers to the brave new world that was The World Wide Web of the '90s.

The series was originally written by Scott Ciencin for four books (*Faceless*, *No Fear*, *Nemesis*, and *Incarnate*). The first three of these were also printed and sold by Random House.

At the time, readers were urged to try and figure out the Lurker's true identity. In [the last chapter written by Ciencin](https://web.archive.org/web/19970810122940/http://www.randomhouse.com/lurkerfiles/incarnate/printeincarnate16.html), we get:

> The Lurker hesitated for a long moment--then removed the Dethboy mask.
>
> Gia couldn't believe what she was seeing. She stared long and hard into the Lurker's face.
>
> "Now you know," the Lurker said.

-- but the reader does not get to learn the Lurker's identity.

From this point, the series was continued by Marc Cerasini (*Apparition*, *Triad*, *Clandestine*). The books got kind of wonky under Cerasini, veering from web-focused thriller/mystery into SF/F.

From October 1997 to January 1998, readers were exhorted to "Get ready for the Lurker Files finale!". However, the finale never came, and the Lurker's identity was never revealed.

**What happened to the Lurker Files?** Why was the series never concluded, and the Lurker's identity never revealed? Did something happen behind the scenes -- perhaps relating to the switchover between Ciencin and Cerasini?

Comment: https://twitter.com/tombquestwiki/status/823082959066562561